# Keyboard pushing layout elements "up" along with it

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-softkeyboard

I have an app with ListView in it and I added search functionality to it. When I press on EditText and it opens keyboard, it  pushes everything in the layout along with it.

Normal layout:
[image]

With keyboard:
[image]

As you can see; the ad, play button, seekbar are all pushed up along with the keyboard, but I don't want that. Is there a way I can avoid this?

I tried adding this to Manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use **"adjustPan"**.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft):

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.